# Function for removing adjacent duplicates in a string recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I need to write a function called `removeDuplicate(string)` with only the string as the parameter. It has to remove all adjacent duplicates. It also has to be recursive. This is what I have so far:

```
def stringClean(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return ""
    elif len(string) == 1:
        return string[0] + string[1:]
    else:
        if string[0] == string[1]:
            return string[0] + stringClean(string[2:])
        else:
            return string[0] + stringClean(string[1:])


print stringClean('Hello') #returns Helo
```

My issue is that it only works in the case that there are only two adjacent duplicates. inputting 'hello' correctly returns 'helo' but inputting 'helllo' or 'hellllo' will return 'hello' instead of 'helo'.

Answer (score 7):

This will do the job:

```
def stringClean(string):
    if not string:
        return ""
    if len(string) == 1:
        return string
    if string[0] == string[1]:
        return stringClean(string[1:])
    return string[0] + stringClean(string[1:])


print stringClean('HHHelllo') #returns Helo
```

Regarding your code, there is no need to return `string[0] + string[1:]` if string is of length 1. Because in such case it consists of only one char, so you just return the char. Now, if `string[0] == string[1]`, then you want to ignore the first char and apply the function on the rest.

Comment: what about it's time complexity ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def removeConsecutiveDuplicates(string):
    if len(string)==0 or len(string)==1:
      return string
    if string[0]==string[1]:
      smaller=string[1:]
      smallout=removeConsecutiveDuplicates(smaller)
      return smallout
    else:
      smaller=string[1:]
      smallout=removeConsecutiveDuplicates(smaller)
      return string[0]+smallout

string = input().strip()
print(removeConsecutiveDuplicates(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
s = "Mississippi"

def no_duplicates(s):
    new_s = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i-1] != s[i]:
            new_s += s[i]
    return new_s

no_duplicates(s)
```

Output: 'Misisipi'

Answer (score -1):

One way to remove adjacent duplicates is to use regular expressions:

```
word="abbababbb"

import re
while(re.search(r'([a-z])\1{1}',word)):
    word=(re.sub(r'([a-z])\1{1}',r'',word))
print(word)
```

output:

```
 bab
```

Comment: This does not work as required. For `abbababbb` It should output `ababab`.